# Simulink Discrete time derivative and integrator with Euler's 3 rules

Tags: controller, simulink

When my input signal is ramp, my scope shows false things. I will add a picture. When my signal is constant, no problems occur, but ramp is false. I want to take derivative and integrator with Euler's forward, backward and bilinear rules.

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Scope doesn't show false things.  It shows exactly what it should for the model you are simulating, and the (default) simulation parameters you are using.

There are multiple ways to change the model to reflect what you are most likely expecting.  One would be to change the sample rate of the unit delay block to be -1 (i.e. inherited) and change the sample rate of the left most gain block to be the rate at which you want the integration to place (e.g. 1 or 0.5, or 0.1)

Comment: Did you make the change I suggested above?

Comment: first ago thank you for look after to me.  :-)  I make some things. but my english is not good so ı dont understand some things.is my blocks are true for take integral with bilinear?and my unit delay block's sample time is t and ı give some values to t .are not they true.

Comment: Read my second paragraph: change the sample time of the unit delay to -1 (which implies inherited), and change the sample time of the first gain block (i.e. the one immediately after the ramp) to `t`.

Comment: when i change sample time of unit delay block , it said  "The sample time after propagation is [0, 1]. Enter a discrete sample time in untitled/delay. and how can i edit gain blocks sample time.i cant find from properties :-) and i wonder where are you from :-)